# Trying to input an array of strings as data for a linked list node

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, dynamic-programming

I've been trying to implement a linked list for a classroom roster in the format

Total Students=

(i)Students name="ABCS"

Total lectures taken =n

Lectures taken="Physics", "Chemistry" ....... n-1

The code executes for the first node, takes input for **classTaken[ ]** and then just exits taking 1 less than the required inputs, no SIGSEGV nothing, it doesnt return to main.
If I comment out **classTaken** the students **name** and Total lectures (**noClass**) work for **noOfStudents** but throw a SIGSEGV after finishing
. I think the return address is being overwritten ,maybe due to wrong allocation .....

Can someone please check out my mallocs to see if ive allocated correctly

PS: Ive commented out the printf statements ive used for debugging

EDIT: OK I've made some changes :

1. changed int to size_t in loops and variables: noClass and noOfStudents
2. put flexible array to end of struct
3. removed casts for allocations
4. malloc'd new->name before scanf

Error still remains (ie program exits after taking 1st input of classTaken[] for first node) I also managed to zero in on the error

```
//writes classes taken by students array of strings     
        for(size_t  j=0; j<(new->noClass); j++){            
            printf("\nEnter class(%d) = ",j+1);
            scanf("%s",new->classTaken[j]);
              }
```

Above loop fails to write to location scanf returns 0,  perror displays "illegal seek"

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>


void prgmSt(void);

#define SUB_MAX 13

struct student{
    char *name;
    int noClass;
    struct student *next;
    char *classTaken[]; 
};

struct student **head; 
char **studentNames;
size_t noOfStudents = 0;

//Makes Single Linked List having noOfStudents nodes
void prgmSt(void){
    struct student **tmp;
    struct student **tmp1;
    for(size_t i=0; i<noOfStudents; i++){
    
        //printf("\nhere1\n");
        struct student *new = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        //printf("\nhere2\n");
        if(new==NULL){
        perror("E:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //printf("\nhere3\n");
        //printf("new=%p\n",new);

    
        printf("\nEnter the name of Student(%d)= ",i+1);
        new->name=malloc(128);
        scanf("%s", new->name);
        studentNames[i] = new->name;
        //printf("\n%s, test1 ", studentNames[i]);
        printf("\nEnter the number of Classes he attended= ");
    
        scanf("%zu",&(new->noClass));
        //printf("\nhere4\n");
        //printf("%d, test2 \n", new->noClass);
        new->classTaken = malloc((new->noClass)*SUB_MAX); //Assumed MAX_LIMIT 
 //of 12+1 characters for 
        //sub name
        if(new->classTaken==NULL){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        new->next = NULL;
    
//writes classes taken by students array of strings     
        for(size_t  j=0; j<(new->noClass); j++){            
            printf("\nEnter class(%d) = ",j+1);
            scanf("%s",new->classTaken[j]);
              }
    
        if(i==0){
            head = &new;
            tmp = &new;
            //printf("head=%p tmp=%p new=%p \n",head,tmp,new);
        } else{
            //printf("here5\n");
            tmp1 = &new;
            (*tmp)->next = *tmp1;
            //printf("here6\n");
            //printf("tmp->next=%p new=%p \n",(*tmp)->next,new);
            //printf("here7\n");
        }

        new = new->next;
    
        //printf("new=%p\n",new);
    
    
    }   
}

int main(void){
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("What is the no of students in class:: ");

    scanf("%d", &noOfStudents);
    studentNames=malloc(noOfStudents*sizeof(char *));

    if(studentNames==NULL){
        perror("E:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    prgmSt();
    //printf("succ");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT : Ive resolved the problem there were 3 main problems(it was a mess)

exactly as i had been told, memory was not allocated to each individual string before scanf

tried to use 2 flexible arrays inside a struct

addresses were being wrongly being assigned to the nodes

I split the structs into student and details, resolved the address assignment, improved readability, and error control ...

#define MAX_LENGTH 13

```
struct student{
    size_t noClass;
    char **classTaken;  
};
struct node{
    struct student* details; 
    struct node *next;
    char *name;

};

struct node **head; 
char **studentNames;
size_t noOfStudents = 0;
void prgmSt(void){
    struct node **tmp;
    int testVar = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<noOfStudents; i++){
    
        struct node * studenti = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        studenti->details = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    
        if((studenti==NULL)|(studenti->details==NULL)){
        perror("E:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        printf("\nEnter the name of Student(max 12)(%zu)= ",i+1);
        studenti->name=malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
           if(studenti->name==NULL){
                perror("E:");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
    
        testVar=scanf("%s", studenti->name);
        if(testVar!=1){
            perror("E:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        studentNames[i] = studenti->name;
    
        printf("\nEnter the number of Classes he attended= ");
        testVar = scanf("%zu",&(studenti->details->noClass));
        if(testVar!=1){
            perror("E:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        studenti->details->classTaken = 
malloc((studenti->details- >noClass)*sizeof(char *)); //Assumed MAX_LIMIT of 
//12+1 characters for sub name
        if(studenti->details->classTaken==NULL){
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        studenti->next = NULL;
        
        for(int  j=0; j<(studenti->details->noClass); j++){
            studenti->details->classTaken[j] = 
            malloc(MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        
            if(studenti->name==NULL){
                perror("E:");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }           
            printf("\nEnter class(%d)(MAX 12 CHARACTERS) = ",j+1);
            testVar=scanf("%s",studenti->details->classTaken[j]);
            if(testVar!=1){
            perror("E:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        }
    
        if(i==0){
            head = &studenti;
            tmp = &studenti;
        } else{
            (*tmp)->next = studenti;
            tmp = &studenti;
        }
        studenti = studenti->next;
    
    
    }   
}
```

Comment: You must allocate and assign buffer to `new->name` before doing `scanf("%s", new->name);`.

Comment: What MikeCAT is saying is that you pass the value of `new->name` to `scanf` before you assign it any value.

Comment: I know I've not free() 'd my mallocs, im planning to scale it up with more entries

Comment: @DavidSchwartz MikeCAT do you mean i have to malloc new->name before i use scanf

Comment: I've made the change ...It still exits after only inputting one node no error nothing

Comment: OT: regarding: `int noOfStudents = 0;`  This variable will never be less than 0 AND the function: `malloc()` is expecting a `size_t` parameter, Therefore, suggest:  `size_t noOfStudents = 0;`

Comment: OT: regarding: `studentNames=(char**)malloc(noOfStudents*sizeof(char *));`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.

Comment: OT: regarding; `scanf("%d", &noOfStudents);`  if you change the type of the variable to: `size_t`, then the correct input format conversion specifier would be: `%zu`

Comment: @janedoe You probably want something like `new->name = malloc (128);` or something to assign it a value that points to a block of memory that can hold the string you read.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz user3629249 guys ive updated the code and found the main error ... classTaken[]  is not being written by scanf ... scanf is giving a return value of 0 when it shld be 1 ..... has it not been malloc'd properly...

Comment: @janedoe Same mistake. You pass `classTaken[j]`'s value to `scanf`. But you never make `classTaken[j]` point to anything. You need to allocate some memory for a string before you call `scanf("%s"...)`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz studenti->details->classTaken[j] = 
            malloc(MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char)); first line of that loop